# Another version of the 3-coloring decision problem?

Tags: graphs, decision-problem, colorings

Given a graph $G$, is there a 3-coloring with colors $c1$, $c2$ and $c3$ such that at most $k$ nodes are given the color $c1$ and that no two adjacent nodes are given the same color?

Is there a decently fast algorithm to solve this? My only solution is to go through every subsets of size $1$ to $k$ and remove those nodes and check if the graph is bipartite. I am also not sure if this runs in polynomial time.

Comment: Is $k$ a fixed constant (like 7) or part of the input?  Have you tried to prove it NP-complete?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133491/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65366306/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: As @D.W. says, it is polynomial time if you take $k$ to be a fixed integer, as you can solve it in $O(n^k \cdot (n+ m))$ time.  Otherwise it is equivalent to 3-coloring: set $k=n$.

Comment: Don't edit your question to delete its content.  That is considered to be vandalizing useful content.  Your question exists not only for you, but also for others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Note that when $k$ is a fixed constant (that is, $k$ is not part of the input, for example $k = 17$ ), then the problem is easy. Indeed, in this case, your suggestion works because $n \choose l$ is polynomial in $n$, for every $l\leq k$. Also, checking whether a graph is bipartite can be done in polynomial time.

If $k$ is part of the input, then your problem is harder than the NP-complete *vertex-deletion graph bipartization* problem. The later problem is defined as follows. Given a graph $G$ and an integer $k\geq 0$, find a subset of at most $k$ vertices such that removing these vertices results in a bipartite graph.

To see why your problem is harder, assume that you have indeed succeeded in coloring a graph with $c_1, c_2$ and $c_3$, where at most $k$ vertices are colored with $c_1$. Then, removing the vertices that are colored with $c_1$ leaves us with a subgraph colored with $c_2$ and $c_3$, and thus the remaining subgraph has to be bipartite as two vertices with same color cannot be neighbors.

The vertex-deletion graph bipartization problem is known to be NP-complete even when restricted to planar graphs. See [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Graph-Bipartization-and-via-Minimization-Choi-Nakajima/26ee744de5cdf22081b0984a57ca342be184dfc1).

Comment: I think the relation with Odd Cycle Transversal is less important than the relation with 3-coloring.

Comment: It's worth noting that Graph Bipartization is fixed-parameter tractable - there is an $O(3^kkmn)$ algorithm (since [improved](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022000018307050)) which is better than $O(n^k(n + m))$ in the fixed-parameter sense.